# std::find in a vector of glm::vec3 is not working (OpenGLTriangle Normals with a crease angle)

Tags: c++, opengl, vector, find, duplicates

i am new in OpenGL and C++ and have a problem my code:

```
vector<glm::vec3> vTempNormals;
glm::vec3 normal{...};

...
if (angle < glm::radians(creaseAngle))
{
    if (angle != 0.0f)
    {
         if (std::find(vTempNormals.begin(), vTempNormals.end(), normal) == vTempNormals.end())
              vTempNormals.push_back(normal);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to avoid duplicates of `glm::vec3 normal` in my vector-container by checking whether the `normal` is not already in the vector and then add it. But it doesn't work as i would expect. Sometimes i still get duplicates. What am I doing wrong?

***Example*** - sometimes it works:
`angle` between `( 0.19509, 0, 0.980785 )` and
the normals to check:

```
( 0.19509, 0, 0.980785 )
( 0.19509, 0, 0.980785 )
(-0.19509, 0, 0.980785 )
( 0, -1, -0 )
( -0.19509, 0, 0.980785 )
( 0, -1, 0 )
( 0, -1, 0 )
```

result:

```
( -0.19509, 0, 0.980785 )
( 0, -1, -0 )
```

***Example*** - sometimes it doesn't work: `angle` between `( 0.19509, 0, 0.980785 )` and the normals to check:

```
( 0, 1, 0 )
( 0, 1, 0 )
( 0.555571, 0, 0.831469 )
( 0.19509, 0, 0.980785 )
( 0.19509, 0, 0.980785 )
( 0, 1, 0 )
( 0.555571, -0, 0.831469 )
```

result:

```
( 0, 1, 0 )
( 0.555571, 0, 0.831469 )
( 0, 1, 0 )
```

Comment: Are you a victim of comparing floats with `==`? Have you read http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html?

Comment: how did you implement the normals using crease angle in opengl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't compare floating point values simply using a simple `x == y` expression as if they were integers.
You have to compare them using a *"threshold"*, a *"tolerance"*, e.g. something like:

```
// Assuming x and y are doubles
if (fabs(x - y) < threshold) {
    // x and y are "near enough", so assume "x == y"
    ...
}
```

[This document](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html), which is often cited in cases like this, goes in details about the subject.

In case of vectors, you may check if they are *"almost equal"* using the **difference vector**, e.g.

```
 // I don't know the details of your glm::vec3 class;
 // anyway, this code assumes that there is a 3D vector class
 // that properly overloads operator-(), returning
 // the vector difference between the two vector operands. 
 Vector3D delta = v2 - v1; 
 if (delta.Length() < threshold)) {
     // ... Assume "v1 == v2"
 }
```

Or if you are comparing just **unit vectors** (like "normals" in your question seem to suggest), you may use the **dot product** to compare them more efficiently, checking that the angle between the directions of those unit vectors is *"small enough"* (i.e. less than some threshold).

Assuming that you define a proper way of comparing your vectors, you can use [**`std::find_if()`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) (instead of `std::find()`) providing a proper **lambda** with your custom comparison code.

Comment: thanks very much, it helped me a lot! (unfortunately i cant upvote you yet)